# How to add a new line with the same indentation

Tags: vim

Then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Insert mode, a new line is created, but the cursor is placed at the  beginning of the line.

How do I create a new line with the same indentation as the current one?

Comment: and that's how google takes me to here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Adding `set autoindent`  to your ~/.vimrc can do that for you automagically.

Comment: thanks! there was no .vimrc, is it ok to create a new one?

Comment: yes, under your home directory.

Answer (score 9):

I'd also suggest adding this to your .vimrc:

```
set smartindent
```

It will increase the indent in a new block.

Answer (score 5):

Both will annoy you when pasting, as Vim will try and indent everything on the fly.

Prior to pasting enter:

```
:set paste
```

Comment: This is true in the terminal.  If you're using gvim you shouldn't need this.

Comment: In complex situations (virtual machines, remote desktops, ...), even `gvim` will not have access to the clipboard. On the other hand, running `vim` locally will have access to the clipboard and `vim` can paste properly if you use `"*p` or `"+p`. Sometimes `vim` and `:set paste` and 'dumb' pasting-raw-to-the-terminal are the only option.

Answer (score 0):

At bottom of the file, I'm using:

```
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

For example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos-7
RUN ...
CMD ...

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

If you want keep the indentation only, use `# vim: st ai si`